# ElasticSearch can't set value to added additional field

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash

I have add a new filed to my ElasticSearch model

```
PUT clients_index/_mapping/external 
{
  "properties": {
        "messagelvl" : { "type" : "string"} 
      }
}
```

Then I try to send logs like this in JSON format

```
{"messagelvl":"DEBUG","debug_timestamp":"2016-10-30 18:16:17,175","debug_thread":"main","debug_file":"DoSomeLogs.java", "debug_line":"18","debug_message":"DEGUB MESSAGE ID! 14"}
```

But what I can see is only

```
DEGUB MESSAGE ID!
```

In my elasticsearch log

```
@timestamp:October 30th 2016, 18:17:20.494 port:51,299 @version:1 host:127.0.0.1 message:playgroundxptERROR MESSAGE ID! 29tmainpw@pxy type:webserver_prod _id:AVgWKpsas5kNO8gnk1_6 _type:webserver_prod _index:clients_index _score: -
```

Also I see my field `messagelvl` in `Hide Missing Fields` and when I try to search by this field result is

```
October 30th 2016, 18:17:20.494  -
```

My JSON model when I open log is:

```
{
  "_index": "clients_index",
  "_type": "webserver_prod",
  "_id": "AVgWKpsas5kNO8gnk1_6",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2016-10-30T15:17:20.494Z",
    "port": 51299,
    "@version": "1",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "message": "playgroundxpt\u0000\u0014ERROR MESSAGE ID! 29t\u0000\u0004mainpw\u0004\u0000\u0000@pxy",
    "type": "webserver_prod"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1477840640494
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1477840640494
  ]
}
```

I don't understand why it not set value to my `messagelvl` filed from JSON message?

Comment: Where is this "Hide Missing Fields"?

Comment: With `PUT clients_index/_mapping/external` you are changing the mapping for the type called `external`. But the document you showed is for the type `webserver_prod` and the timestamps don't match either.